# Changing column data in kendo grid conditionally

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to change value of some columns in kendo grid conditionally. As the grid id already bound to some data but it needs some modifications in
data which is already bound.

I have used couple of sample codes that i got from stackoverflow but none of them reflecting. There is no change in grid data

1st way

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

            var items = grid.dataSource.data();
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i]["MatchCount"] = "4";
            }
```

2nd way tried

```
var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()[0];
        dataItem.set("MatchCount", "CCC");
```

3rd way

```
  var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()[0];
     dataItem.set("MatchCount", "50");
```

The way grid is bound is below:

```
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: DataSource,

        columns:
        [
            { field: "RowId", title: "RowId", hidden: true },
            {
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name",
                width: 150,
                editable: false,
                headerTemplate: createHeaderTemplate("Last Name")

            },
           {
                field: "MatchCount",
                width: 120,
                editable: false,
                template: "#if(MatchCount == 0){#<span>#=MatchCount#</span>#}else{#<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='ShowMatches(&quot;#=LastName#&quot;,&quot;#=FirstName#&quot;,${MatchCount},&quot;#=MatchIds#&quot;);' style='margin-left:50px' >#=MatchCount#</a>#}#"
            }

        ],
        edit: function (e) {
            //e.container.find("input[name='Name']").each(function () { $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled") });       
        },
        editable: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing ok in attempts 2 and 3. Perhaps you need to run [`refresh()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-refresh) method:

```
dataItem.set("MatchCount", "50");
grid.refresh();
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ogiPe)